# MalformedPolicy when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation to upload a policy JSON: Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to attach a policy to an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI with a JSON file containing the policy as input. My command is:

`aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket myBucketName --policy file://policy.json`

However, I keep getting this error:

`An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'`

The contents of the policy file is:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/redacted"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My JSON file seems correctly formatted. The first byte is definitely a '{'. The file path is very simple, the file is in the current working directory where the cli is being used. There are no spaces or other characters before the '{'. This is the first time I'm getting this error. I have uploaded and applied other policies successfully before now. This policy is failing though.

I compared the contents of previous policies that succeeded, and don't see anything obvious I'm doing wrong.

Just for sanity, I changed the policy to just be an open and close brace { } without any contents, and I get the same error.

Note that the arn has been redacted in the JSON shown, but I have confirmed it is correct for my account; the issue does not seem arn related.

I also see this related question: [AWS S3 Bucket giving 'policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534527/aws-s3-bucket-giving-policies-must-be-valid-json-and-the-first-byte-must-be)
The solution in this case was that there were spaces included before the opening brace '{'. This is not the case for me.

Also, I tried adding the "Version" field but this did not fix the error ("Version": "2008-10-17",)

Further update: I tried applying the policy using the AWS Management console. The exact same JSON saves and applies successfully! What now?

Why is this JSON policy file invalid?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue was the character encoding of the JSON file.

The file was generated by a Powershell script; and without me realizing, the encoding from Powershell is UTF-16 LE BOM.

Changing the statement that created the .json file to use the ANSII encoding fixed the issue:

> Out-File -FilePath "policy.json" -InputObject $policy
> -Encoding ansii

I suspect that AWS CLI uses UTF-8 encoding, and was unhappy with the UTF-16 LE BOM format.

If you get this error, and you're sure that your JSON file begins with a '{', then ensure that the character encoding of your file is set to UTF-8 or ANSII.